# Comparing Multiple Columns with and without NULL values

Tags: mysql

5, Not sure what am I doing wrong, please help. As it seems in a query on multiple column comparison to find least value, 
NULL continues to show up as a Resultant instead of least value

```
SELECT
  IF(col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL OR col4 IS NULL OR col5 IS NULL, 
      COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5), 
      LEAST(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
  ) As Resultant 
from db.tablename 
Group by Id;
```

Alternatively tried CASE select without much success. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of the `GROUP BY`? You have no aggregates in there.

Comment: Are you sure that at least 1 of `col` is not null ?

Comment: Sorry, it is Select *, Resultant; there are Id categories.

Comment: @a1ex07 Scenario is , there are not null/null values in all columns. If col1, col2 are null in a row, there are col3, col4, col5 with values/ not null in the same row. I tried assigning value to Null as '999' [ Select *, MIN(IFNULL(Col1, '999'),  MIN(IFNULL(Col2, '999')...] but that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: Is `Id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table?

Answer (score 1):

if null is considered 0

```
select least(ifnull(col1,0),ifnull(col2,0),ifnull(col3,0),ifnull(col4,0),ifnull(col5,0))
as Resultant
from db.tablename
Group by Id;
```

if null is condered max

```
select least(ifnull(col1,~0>>1),ifnull(col2,~0>>1),ifnull(col3,~0>>1),ifnull(col4,~0>>1),ifnull(col5,~0>>1))
as Resultant
from db.tablename
Group by Id;
```

Comment: Thanks @ Melvin, ran both queries Resultant for a Col1 (null), Col2(null), Col3(not null), Col4(not null), Col5(not null) Brings Resultant (null) for that row, only when all Col1 to Col5 are not null the resultant fetches not null and that is also the least, correct, value amongst all columns.

Comment: are you saying that the ifnull(Col1,0) does not result to 0 when Col1 is null?

Comment: Instead of ifnull( col1,0) I changed to ifnull(col1,999) with '999'as the value for null, so that I can have non null/least value of the five columns as resultant values. But the resultant bring null instead of least value that exists in five columns when compared. It also brings least value of the five when there is no null value substituted.

Comment: ifnull(col1,0) is if we are going to treat nulls as 0 value, while
ifnull(col1,~0>>1) is if we are going to treat nulls as max int value

remember that you may reach the point where 999 is also a result of your query or could be higher making nulls interpreted as 999 to be the least.

Comment: Thanks again,Mevin, though I would appreciate your help in resolving this: there are not null/null values in all columns from Col1 to Col5. If col1, col2 are null in a row, there are col3 (160), col4 (170), col5(170) with values/ not null in the same row. I want to ignore Null Values and select the least from the non null values ( which would in this case be (160), Am I following the correct query to find the resultant value that is lowest /least when compared in Five columns with and without nulls?   OR IF you know any alternative to GREATEST_NONNULL(...); or Least_NONNULL(col1, col2...) ?

Comment: Simply running GREATEST_NONNULL(...); or Least_NONNULL(col1, col2...) ? – doesnt seem to be working on MySQL 5.5 And I want to get only least of NONNULL values from 5 columns. Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand why it fails on your end when the query I have used is working on my end. can you provide the exact sql statement you are running and probably a sample data?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sure doing something wrong: Sample data is as following:                                                             use db;
Create table test ( ID varchar(12) Primary key, Col1 varchar(12), 
Col2 varchar(12), Col3 varchar (12), Col4 varchar (12), col5 varchar (12)) ;
Insert into test ( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 ) Values ( 'group1', '160','','170','160', '170');
Insert into test ( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 ) Values ( 'group2', '','','170','170', '160');
Insert into test ( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 ) Values ( 'group3', '140','','','170', '160');

Comment: And the query: 
select *, least(ifnull(Col1,999),
ifnull(Col2,999),ifnull(Col3,999),
ifnull(Col4,999),ifnull(Col5,999))
as Resultant
from db.test
Group by ID; Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: seems like you mistakenly consider empty strings with null values. they are different. you may want to convert the columns to numeric instead of varchar

Comment: Seems not working -use db;
Create table test3 ( ID INT(12) Primary key, Col1 INT(12), 
Col2 INT(12), Col3 INT (12), Col4 INT (12), col5 INT (12)) ;
Insert into test3 ( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 ) Values ( 'group1', '160','0','170','160', '170');
Insert into test3 ( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 ) Values ( 'group2', '0','0','170','170', '160');
Insert into test3 ( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 ) Values ( 'group3', '140','0','0','170', '160'); QUERY brings  '0' in the Resultant. much appreciated your help. Thanks

Comment: you cannot insert varchar on int column. you should have defined the ID column as varchar while the rest of the columns int. also for the insert to simulate the null values, you may insert null instead of '0'.

Comment: re-typing error, pardon me, it was ID Varchar(12) instead and also defaults were put to '0'.Please try running it again.

Comment: am i going to run that? i'm doing hypothetical analysis only. you execute the code and that should be working already.

Comment: Sorry Melvin, you said earlier "query I have used is working on my end" that led me assuming probably, wrong .Again, Thanks for everything

Comment: using the basic query and syntax it is working, ifnull(col1,0) returns 0 and ifnull(col1,~0>>1) returns max int value. Also the least function also works. that's what I meant and that's the basic concept.

Comment: Again, Thanks a lot, much appreciated all your help Melvin

Answer (score 0):

For people with the case such that there are only two values to compare, you can do this:

```
GREATEST(ifnull(a,b), ifnull(b,a))
```